# Downloading County Shapefile from ONS

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, esri

I'm trying to download the Ultra Generalised Clipped Boundaries from the ONS as defined [here](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/ea553223-736e-4b9e-9ba3-9fd6280ab5ec/counties-december-2017-ultra-generalised-clipped-boundaries-in-england). I plan to use it to display a Choropleth map with ggplot.

However, I get the message below when I use readOGR.

*Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer*

The download and unzip seems to be working and it comes up as an ESRI Shape document.

What am I doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)

dest_zip_file <- "Counties_December_2017_Ultra_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England.zip"
shape_file_name <- "Counties_December_2017_Ultra_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England"

download.file("http://geoportal1-ons.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/c6404b30a373457e9d87f724dd57585c_4.zip?outSR={%22latestWkid%22:27700,%22wkid%22:27700}",
              dest_zip_file)
unzip(dest_zip_file, paste0(shape_file_name,".shp"))

county_shapes <- readOGR(dsn = ".",
                         layer = shape_file_name,
                         verbose = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're unzipping your folder into a single file - .shp - you should actually have several files as part of your 'shape file' including the .shx and .dbf files.

You could fix up your code by unzipping all of the files and reading in:

```r
unzip(dest_zip_file)

county_shapes <- readOGR(dsn = ".",
                         layer = shape_file_name,
                         verbose = TRUE)
```

On a side note, if you're looking for UK geographic boundaries I would always recommend [geoportal](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/) where you can often find links to download the geojson via API. For instance I found a link for the 2017 county boundaries and read in using `sf`:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
county <- read_sf('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/c6404b30a373457e9d87f724dd57585c_2.geojson')
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = county)
```

[image: 2017 county boundaries]

Comment: That's great @Chris. I've used a different source at https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/counties-and-unitary-authorities-december-2019-boundaries-uk-buc that covers the whole UK (using county <- read_sf('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b216b4c8a4e74f6fb692a1785255d777_0.geojson')).  Out of intertest, do you know why yours seems to have gaps?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is gappy like that. If you read in the file from the link in your original post it is the same so it seems like an intentional feature of the data.

Comment: My other link does have them all, but the grouping is at a higher level, e.g. Highland. Looking for something with actual counties eg Cheshire, not administrative regions like East Cheshire. Will have to keep looking.

Comment: It didn't when I opened it! Judging from the answer and comments here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174727/ordnance-survey-missing-counties-from-boundary-line-shapefile some areas of the country are simply not in a county

Comment: The map rendered seems to be counties -- which does not include Unitary Authorities, etc.